# $3\sigma$ rule for multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I was wondering if the [$3\sigma$ rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68-95-99.7_rule) that holds for 1D normal distribution also holds for multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20083/density-of-normal-distribution-as-dimensions-increase/

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "three standard deviations".  If you mean three times the square root of the expected square of the distance to the mean, then you get a different answer compared to your meaning three times the standard deviation of just one of the variates

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short answer: no, the [rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) does not hold in more dimensions.

In the general case (multivariate with arbitrary covariance matrix), the natural generalization of the "normalized distance from the mean", $d = |x -u|/\sigma$, is given by the **Mahalanobis distance**

$$d = \sqrt{ ({\bf x} - {\bf \mu})^t {\bf \Sigma}^{-1} ({\bf x} - {\bf \mu})}$$

Points of constant Mahalanobis distance lie on an ellipsoid.

If (and only if) the components are independent and with same variance, then $d=\frac{\|{\bf x} - {\bf \mu}\|}{\sigma}$.

The threshold value that contains most (say, 99%) of the distribution varies with the dimension. Or, put in other way, the probability that $x$ takes a (Mahalanobis) distance less than (say) $d=3.0$ decreases with the dimension.

This figure, taken from [here](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=QvL-zkr5Ls8C&pg=SA5-PA23&lpg=SA5-PA23) <sub>("Statistics for Imaging, Optics and Phtotononics", Peter Bajorski, fig. 5.21)</sub> (which explains all this in more detail), displays that probability as a function of the dimension, for distances $d=2.0$ and $d=3.0$ ("$2-$sigma" and "$3-$sigma").

[image]

For example, we see that in **5 dimensions** the probability that $x$ lies 'under 3 sigmas' is about $0.9$ (instead of $0.97$), and for '2 sigmas' is around $0.4$ (instead of $0.95$)

Comment: Very nice point!

Comment: Nice answer. You could improve it by giving a reference to the image (including page numbers) that does not depend on an external website.

Answer (score 4):

It is often said that in high dimensions the probability distribution is concentrated away from the center.  So although in 1 D a 3 sigma interval will contain more than 99% of the distribution a three sigma circle for a 2D gaussian with iid components will contain less mass than the 1 D counterpart and the same for 3D compared to 2D etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in a sense. For the 1D case, you need to standardize the normal variate to a standard normal variate $Z\sim N(0,1)$. For the [multivariate normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), each covariate must be not only normally distributed, but *independent*. You also need to know something more, the correlation matrix. Then, your question can be elegantly answered using the [Gaussian copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29#Gaussian_copula). For the $8\times8$ intervals between $\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm\infty\}$ in each coordinate, the 2D discrete probability distribution of discretized independent (zero correlation) standard normal variates would be:
$$
\matrix{1.82\times10^{-6}&0.0000289&0.000183&0.000461&0.000461&0.000183&0.0000289&1.82\times10^{-6}\\0.0000289&0.000458&0.00291&0.00730&0.00730&0.00291&0.000458&0.0000289\\0.000183&0.00291&0.0185&0.0464&0.0464&0.0185&0.00291&0.000183\\0.000461&0.00730&0.0464&0.117&0.117&0.0464&0.00730&0.000461\\0.000461&0.00730&0.0464&0.117&0.117&0.0464&0.00730&0.000461\\0.000183&0.00291&0.0185&0.0464&0.0464&0.0185&0.00291&0.000183\\0.0000289&0.000458&0.00291&0.00730&0.00730&0.00291&0.000458&0.0000289\\1.82\times10^{-6}&0.0000289&0.000183&0.000461&0.000461&0.000183&0.0000289&1.82\times10^{-6}\\}$$

The above was generated in [sage](http://sagemath.org) with the code below: NormalCDF is the normal cumulative density function $\Phi$, $Z=\{z_i\}$ is the set of $9$ boundary values given above (as an array), $p=\{\Phi(z_i)\}$, and $P=\{\Phi(z_i)-\Phi(z_{i-1})\}_{i=1}^8$ are the 1D probabilities of lying within each of the $8$ intervals bounded by these $9$ points, $M=(P_iP_j)$ a matrix representing the CDF of the 2D discrete distribution of lying within interval $(i,j)$, $N$ is an array of array of strings representing each $M_{ij}$ numerically approximated to $3$ places, and $L$ is a string representing $N$ as an unbracketed matrix in LaTeX. The last command displays the LaTeX within sage, assuming you have your worksheet set to display mathematical typesetting.

```
NormalCDF = lambda z: (1+sign(z))/2 if abs(z)==infinity else ((1+erf(z/sqrt(2)))/2).n()
Z = [-infinity]; Z.extend(range(-3,4)); Z.append(infinity)
p = [NormalCDF(z) for z in Z]
P = [p[i]-p[i-1] for i in range(1,len(p))]
M = Matrix(RDF,8,8,[[P[i]*P[j] for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)])
N = [[latex((P[i]*P[j]).n(digits=3)) for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
L = '\\matrix{' + (''.join(['& '.join(N[k])+'\\\\' for k in range(8)])) + '}'
LatexExpr(L)
```

Comment: From the table above it seems that the %age of values lie within one standard deviation is not 68% as is the case with 1D? Moreover,  is it fine to say that for 3$\sigma$ rule to hold, the each dimension should be independent and uncorrelated? Can you copy the 2D Gaussian function you have used for obtaining the above values.

Comment: To recover the 1D rule, you need to sum rows or columns. If you sum the $3$rd and $4$th (rows/columns), you'll get $68$%.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have one confusion if you can help please. I read at several places that when there is no correlation, [the n-dimension multivariate Gaussian is simply the  multiplication of n 1-dimensional Gaussian distribution][1]. When I am integrating the 2D function in the [document][1], i am getting only 46.6% within 1 standard deviation. [1]:http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~mchung/teaching/MIA/reading/diffusion.gaussian.kernel.pdf

Comment: Well, there must be an error somewhere, as your reading suggests. The density of a multivariate with independent univariates factors into the product of its marginals. I suspect you are integrating from $-\sigma$ to $\sigma$ in each dimension. This corresponds to the categorical variables *both* being in one of the two middle columns/rows, and has probability about $4\times11.7$%. This is correct, but it is a central, not a marginal, probability. Indeed, `4*M[3,3]` yields $0.466064942674$. Marginal probabilites must sum an entire row or column, to eliminate a variable.

Comment: Yes, I was integrating from $-\sigma$ to $\sigma$ in each dimension. Actually I am interested in probability of 2D Gaussian distribution within some radius from the mean. That is why I integrated from $-\sigma$ to $\sigma$ in each dimension. Now I understood the difference between the central and marginal probability. Actually I need central probability for my problem. Thank you very much for such a nice explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is more a caveat than an answer (@leonbloy's is more then good enough), but I fell for this trap and would like others to avoid it.

In $D$ dimensions, the fraction of samples within Mahalanobis distance $3$ is NOT $0.997^D$.

This is wrong even if the covariance matrix is diagonal (even, the identity). Yes, a multivariate Gaussian is separable; and yes, along each principal axis the probability of being within three standard deviations is $0.997$.

However, the region within Mahalobonis distance $3$ is a hyperellipsoid (hypersphere), while the the intersection of the $\pm3\sigma$ 1D regions is a hyperrectangle (hypercube). The latter has an integral value of $0.997^D$, while the former is considerably smaller (and more difficult to compute).

Answer (score 1):

As a small helper for all that want to find the generic $m$-sigma rules of $n$-dimensional hyper-ellipsoids:

Simply fire up wolframalpha and type in:

$Q(n/2, 0, m^2/2)$.

$Q$ stands for the generalized regularized incomplete gamma function.

For $n=1$ and $m=3$ you will obtain $0.997300...$,

for $n=2$ and $m=3$ the result is:
$0.988891...$

and for $n=3$ and $m=3$:
$0.970709...$.

This answer is was inspired by the post of leonbloy.

Comment: Dear @Elarion, this answer appears to be the strongest generalisation while I want to use it in my research. I only need an isotropic normal distribution case where the dimensionality and the standard deviation vary. Could you please offer me the reference? Thanks in advance.